# In Modus Ponens, Why Does F —> T Resolve to T (not F)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Logicians,

Can you explain a seemingly curious facet of *Modus Ponens*?

Given *Modus Ponens* is expressed as:

$$p \to q $$

Supported by this Truth Table:

| Line | $p$ | $q$ | $p \to q$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | T | T |
| 2 | T | F | F |
| 3 | F | T | T |
| 4 | F | F | T |

**QUESTION: Why does Line 3 resolve to $T$? It seems that $F \to T$ should resolve to $F$**. No?

Your assistance in understanding this apparent contradiction is requested with gratitude.

Comment: If you assume something false, anything can be proven true.  So, the implication that a false thing implies anything is always true.  That's why the last two rows are true.  For example, if $0 = 1$, then I can add 1 to both sides to get $1 = 2$.

Comment: You're right: to some degree, this is a matter of convention, not some physical principal. It _does_ allow a simpler set-up for propositional logic, and is not completely crazy... so there we are.

Comment: Note the distinction between the phrases "$q$ is a necessary condition for $p$ to occur" and "$q$ is both a necessary *and sufficient* condition for $p$ to occur"... the distinction between the expression $p\implies q$ and the expression $p\iff q$

Comment: @JMoravitz, good point. That does connect the issue with colloquial usage, too. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett It's why we argue the empty set is a subset of every set, so it's importance in mathematical reasoning is makes it more like an axiom/definition.  But regarding your comment, you might  enjoy "The Meanings of Implication" by John Corcoran.  One realizes quickly all the subtleties in the natural language uses of the term, "implication".

Comment: @amWhy, thanks for the recommendation! :)

Comment: $p \to q$ is **not** [*Modus Ponens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens#Formal_notation).

Answer (score 0):

An implication is always true if the antecedent (the $p$ in the $p\to q$) is false. This is just true by definition. To offer an intuitive explanation, let's say a statement is true if I don't lie, and false if I lie.

Now consider me telling you this:

"If I race you on Tuesday, then I will win."

Now, if I didn't race you on Tuesday (say we raced on Wednesday and I lost)--did I lie? I say I didn't tell, since we didn't race on Thursday. I would've only been lying if I raced you on Tuesday and lost.

So, a person only lies (an implication is only false) if they make a statement of the form "if $p$, then $q$" and then they do $p$ but not $q$. They didn't lie if they didn't do $p$, even if they went on to do $q$ or not.